# RTL: how to debug internal elements or part of the rendered DOM

Tags: react-testing-library, testing-library

when using screen, there is a method `screen.debug()` which pretty prints the whole DOM

in the docs there is also a mention of `prettyDOM` method, which can be used to pretty print the DOM of any element. But it's usage is not shown for elements which are rendered.

it seems like we can get the element using a query and then use prettyDOM on it to just debug a particular part of the rendered DOM

Is that the suggested way to debug parts of the rendered DOM?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to debug a particular part of the document, pass your query results to `screen.debug()`.

`screen.debug()` accepts 0-n elements as parameters, allowing you to debug the whole DOM, a single element, or multiple elements:

```
import {screen} from '@testing-library/dom'

document.body.innerHTML = `
  <button>test</button>
  <span>multi-test</span>
  <div>multi-test</div>
`

// debug document
screen.debug();
// debug single element
screen.debug(screen.getByText('test'));
// debug multiple elements
screen.debug(screen.getAllByText('multi-test'));
```

See the [screen.debug API docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/#screendebug) for more information.